# ChartJS 'Line chartjs' does not show output in NodeRED?

Tags: chart.js, node-red, kepserverex

My requirement is to output 2 y-axis chart with real-time data readings in NodeRED. I have installed `ChartJS` package in NodeRED and now according to the documentation of the package there should be `PATH, Title, X-Axis, Y-Axis,  Payload`. But I couldn't find the `Payload` tab anywhere in the `Line Chartjs` node?

[image]

Ref : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-chartjs

[image]

So I assumed that I have to add the code which belonged to `Payload` inside a function node before the `Line Chartjs node`.

What I have tried : (my function node)

```
var left = {payload : msg.payload.readResults[0].v };
var right = {payload : msg.payload.readResults[1].v };


//return [[left,right]];


const labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: left,
      borderColor: '#ff0000',
      backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
      yAxisID: 'leftCamber',
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: right,
      borderColor: '#0000ff',
      backgroundColor: '#0000ff',
      yAxisID: 'rightCamber',
    }
  ]
};

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    stacked: false,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Multi Axis'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      leftCamber: {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'left',
      },
      rightCamber: {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'right',

        // grid line settings
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false, // only want the grid lines for one axis to show up
        },
      },
    }
  },
};

const actions = [
  {
    name: 'CamberGraph',
    handler(chart) {
      chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
        dataset.data = chart.data.labels.length
      });
      chart.update();
    }
  },
];
```

Here I have tried to get the 2 HTTP outputs I've named as `left` and `right` as my datasets(2 y-axis) vs hardcoded x-axis(1 through 10) which will be `Footage` later on.

PS : I have returned the `left` and `right` using return statement and it's outputting the values as I expected.

Currently I do not get any output in my debug window as well as in my `ChartJS Line Chart` when I inject the node. Using what I've tried so far can anybody show where I've done wrong or add/remove anything to make the graph work?

Thank you!